# How can you calculate column sums based on a condition using data.table?

Tags: r, sum, data.table, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a table of IDs and 1000 columns of random values. I want to group the IDs and calculate the number of values less than 0.01 for each column.

I used a loop to merge a table iteratively but have to access the column name using `eval` and `parse`. Unfortunately it's taking too long to run. I've implemented a similar for loop for a different problem in the past so I know iterative merging doesn't take that long. I think the `eval` and `parse` is what's slowing the code down. Is there a way to do this without using those functions?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 13), 
  col1 = rnorm(39), 
  col2 = rnorm(39), 
  col3 = rnorm(39))
```

I need to produce the following for each column: `data[,sum(col1 < 0.01)]; data[,sum(col2 < 0.01)]; data[,sum(col3 < 0.01)]`

```
columns <- colnames(data)[2:ncol(data)]
d <- data[,.N, keyby = ID][,N := NULL]
for (col in 1:length(columns)) {
    sum_table <-  data[, sum(eval(parse(text = ..columns[col])) < 0.01), by = ID]
d <- d[sum_table]
}
```

I would like to be able to reproduce this without using `eval` and `parse` so the run time is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) after specifying the columns of interest in `.SDcols` and ge the number of elements that are less than 0.01

```
data[, lapply(.SD,  function(x) sum(x < 0.01)), .SDcols = col1:col3]
```

Or convert the `.SD` to a logical matrix and get the `colSums`

```
data[, colSums(.SD < 0.01), .SDcols = col1:col3]
```

---

If there is grouping variable, specify the `by` as well

```
data[, lapply(.SD,  function(x) sum(x < 0.01)), .SDcols = col1:col3, by = ID]
data[, as.list(colSums(.SD < 0.01)), .SDcols = col1:col3, by = ID]
```

Comment: Yeah that was quick and simple, works great. I don't always think about `lapply` when using `data.table`.

Comment: Re the by=, you can also reshape `dcast(melt(data, id="ID")[value < 0.01], ID ~ variable)` @abbas It may make sense to keep the data in the melted format if doing many operations like this.